# 'FileSavePicker.SuggestedStartLocation' not specific enough

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, filesavepicker

I am using a [FileSavePicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207871) so the user can choose where to save a file. I want the default location the file is saved be 'Documents\MyFolder', but the field SuggestedStartLocation won't take a filepath; only the very limited list of [PickerLocationId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207890) enumerations can be accepted.

I notice that once I save a file it will automatically open 'Documents\MyFolder' in the future, as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465199), yet I can't find any way to force that to *always* be 'Documents\MyFolder'.

How can I either:

A.) Get FileSavePicker to default to the location 'Documents\MyFolder'

B.) Replace FileSavePicker with something else that acts as desired